Concatenating strings strange forward slash
I am doing some processing on the JSON output of cargo metadata using JQ and a loop. To simplify the situation I have made a simple case below
extractor='(?:path\\+file:\\/{3})(.*?)(?:#.*)?@[\\d\\.]+'
expr=".workspace_members[] | match(\"$extractor\").captures[0].string"

input='{ "workspace_members": [
    "path+file:///C:/Users/me/project1#project-1@0.1.0",
    "path+file:///C:/Users/me/project2#project-2@0.1.0",
    "path+file:///C:/Users/me/project3@0.1.0",
    "path+file:///C:/Users/me/project4#project-4@0.1.0",
    "path+file:///C:/Users/me/project5#project-5@0.1.0"
] }'

echo $input | jq -r "$expr" | while read cratePath; do
    echo "Here $cratePath"
done

This works fine, I get as output from the echo "Here $cratePath" line the following
$ ./private/test.sh
Here C:/Users/me/project1
Here C:/Users/me/project2
Here C:/Users/me/project3
Here C:/Users/me/project4
Here C:/Users/me/project5

However I now want to build a child path from $cratePath. When concatenating the strings a rather strange thing happens. Changing the last line to
echo $input | jq -r "$expr" | while read cratePath; do
    echo "Here $cratePath/src"
done

Outputs
/src C:/Users/me/project1
/src C:/Users/me/project2
/src C:/Users/me/project3
/src C:/Users/me/project4
/src C:/Users/me/project5

Why is /src printed first? How can I get it to concatenate at the end. Leaving the first as C:/Users/me/project1/src for example?

/src is printed last, but after a $'\r', which returns the cursor to the left and overwrites Here.

$createPath ends with a carriage return.

I'm not sure how that's happening, since that would make the JSON invalid and jq should reject it.

Ah yes I had suspicions of a carriage return. (this on git bash on windows, so there might be some oddities). Is there a way to clean it up? Maybe a flag in read?

Make sure your script is saved as a POSIX text file, not a DOS text file.

If the carriage returns are actually coming from jq (not something else, like the script itself), and you are actually using bash (not some other shell), you can use while IFS=$'\r' read cratePath... (see my answer here). Also, be sure to double-quote all variable references (e.g. echo "$input" instead of echo $input) -- shellcheck.net is good at spotting common mistakes like this.
